# Uploading a png to imgur using javascript

Tags: javascript, png, imgur

I'm trying to use `Javascript` to upload a `png` to [imgur](http://imgur.com/). I've used the code directly from the Imgur API [example](http://api.imgur.com/examples), but I don't think I am passing the png file properly as I get an error message saying `file.type is undefined`. I think the file is ok as I've tried this with a few different pngs. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function upload(file) {
   // file is from a <input> tag or from Drag'n Drop
   // Is the file an image?
   if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) return;

   // It is!
   // Let's build a FormData object
   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append("image", file); // Append the file
   fd.append("key", "mykey"); // Get your own key: http://api.imgur.com/

   // Create the XHR (Cross-Domain XHR FTW!!!)
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json"); // Boooom!
   xhr.onload = function() {
      // Big win!
      // The URL of the image is:
      JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).upload.links.imgur_page;
   }

   // Ok, I don't handle the errors. An exercice for the reader.
   // And now, we send the formdata
   xhr.send(fd);
}
</script>
</head>   

<body>

<button type="button" onclick="upload('test.png')">upload to imgur</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

The `png` file `test.png` is stored in the same directory as my html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you are using expects that you use input element (type=file) to upload some image. Try [this example](http://29a.ch/2011/9/11/uploading-from-html5-canvas-to-imgur-data-uri). You can access image data using a Canvas [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript).

To summarize, you'll need to do this:

1. Create new Image with your file (needs to be on local domain)
2. Draw the image to a Canvas at onload
3. Extract image data using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)
4. Pass that data to imgur [like here](http://29a.ch/2011/9/11/uploading-from-html5-canvas-to-imgur-data-uri)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. For adding an image to the canvas, is that the image `id`? I assume I can't refer to it using the filename, based on @skimberk1's comment.

Comment: There's no way to refer to the image using filename. You'll need to load it to an img element and then load its contents to a canvas using drawImage. It is important to do this latter part at the img's onload handler. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks bebraw, that helps me understand the flow. I'm experimenting with http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ at the moment; it looks like it will do part of these steps.

Answer (score 3):

The file has to be a `File` object created with the HTML5 fileAPI, you can't just give it a file name and expect it to work.

Javascript has no access to the filesystem, it can only access files that are given to it using either drag and drop or a file input.