# Three.js Screenshot

Tags: javascript, three.js, screenshot, html, html2canvas

I need to make screenshot of website. I tried using html2canvas and all and it's working. But problem is i'm using THREE.WebGLRenderer and THREE.CSS3DRenderer (for html in webgl)... So when I make screenshot it makes images only from WebGLRenderer. CSS3DRenderer is ignored and I don't know how to make screenshot image from both renderers. I'm using this solution:
[Take screenshot of <body> with html2canvas and store img as JS var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401350/take-screenshot-of-body-with-html2canvas-and-store-img-as-js-var)

Answer (score 11):

you can use this code `var Render=new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true});`

and a function onclick print:

```
$("#btn_print").click(function() {
                window.open( Render.domElement.toDataURL("image/png"), "Final");
                return false;
            });
```

Example online:
http://develoteca.com/Panel/ clic on button Print

The key is: {antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true} in object WebGLRenderer

,regards.

visit:http://develoteca.com

Comment: Yeah I tried that was but still i'm using two renderers (THREE.WebGLRenderer and THREE.CSS3DRenderer). It's working perfectly for 3D objects and all but my emmbed html is not on screenshot :D I think I'm going to use smht else for html inside webgl.

Comment: Is there a way to download this screenshot ?

Answer (score 2):

Try understanding the code of this chrome extension [Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg). You can find the code in ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/<extention_id_in_link> after installing it.

It uses [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab). Refer the documentation. As it's an API provided by chrome browser to interact with its tabs it works only on Google Chrome.

Comment: Well this isn't exactly the answer but it pointed me in the right direction. This is exactly what I was looking for: 

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/screen-sharing.html

Thank you. I am awarding you the bounty now but next time please be clear about your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this feature thanks to the [file saver js lib](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filesaver.js"></script>

$("#btn_print").click(function() {
    Render.domElement.toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "Final");
    });
});
```

I hope this helps !