# how do I initialize html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot, html2canvas

I downloaded the [html2canvas javascript plugin](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) that allows me to take a screenshot of a web page on the client side (the browser), but I can't figure out what files I'm supposed to include in the header of the page to use it, [I've seen examples on how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250505/how-to-upload-a-screenshot-using-html2canvas), but what files should I include?

Comment: Can I suggest you take a look at feedback.js? It is a work in progress (not mine by the way) but is a nice wrapper around html2canvas... https://github.com/niklasvh/feedback.js

Comment: I did look at it, but I don't want the wrapper I want the thing itself

Thnx for the suggestion anyways :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [various](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/examples/demo.html) [demo](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/examples/demo2.html) [pages](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/examples/existing_canvas.html), it appears you only need [the single](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/tree/master/dist) script([a](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/dist/html2canvas.js) or [b](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js)) included in your header.

This is different from an older version of the script, which needed jQuery, `html2canvas.js`, and `jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js`.

I can't comment on the two other scripts included in the /dist directory(the svg ones), given I can't find any examples of their use.

Comment: I put jquery and jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js, but there's not html2canvas.js
here's the files tree :
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

Comment: @SlimFadi Actually, there is.  It isn't in the source you're looking at, but the zip files present on that repository.  See [the downloads page](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/downloads)

Comment: ya got it, thnx a lot :)
wish I could vote you up, but it's not letting me because of my "reputation" :)

Comment: @SlimFadi If you like this answer, please click the outlined checkmark below the down arrow.  This will accept the answer.