# Save HTML DIV as an image with save as pop up

Tags: javascript, image, html, canvas

I want to make a web app which makes comics. It's very basic and I don't know Canvas very well. The user can upload 2 images and they appear in two divs. Then these divs are in one whole div along with other comic elements. What I want is that when the user clicks on a button, a 'save as' dialog box pops up which saves the whole div as an image.

[This page](http://ragemaker.net/) does that but it works in flash!

Please don't rate in negative or say it's a possible copy or something! I've been finding a solution for hours on the net. Canvas2Image and Html2Canvas ain't for me because I ain't using canvas. Also I tried "Joel Schlundt" answer on [capture div into image using html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595541/capture-div-into-image-using-html2canvas) using that. Please tell a possible solution or maybe how I can make that div come into canvas as an image automatically and then save that canvas as an image.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to familiarise yourself with canvas, rather than pleading against down-votes, and question-closure?

Comment: But I can't even find a solution to save canvas as image. I have no problem in canvas if you can tell me a way to save canvas as image @DavidThomas. I couldn't make that answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595541/capture-div-into-image-using-html2canvas work!

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot get a "Save as" dialog that works consistently, however what you'd need to get the image data is probably data url related. I'll mock up a jsFiddle example and post it soon

Comment: This is about as close as I'm aware is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/schme16/Z3E4T/2/ There really isn't a way to get around using canvas... sorry I could find anything better :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can easily use canvas to combine your cartoon image with the user’s images.**

Here’s how to create a canvas on the fly and combine all the images:

```
// create a temporary canvas and size it
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width=awindow.width;
canvas.height=awindow.height;

// draw all 3 images into 1 combined image
ctx.drawImage(back,0,65);
ctx.drawImage(person,0,0,person.width,person.height,200,125,71,200);
ctx.drawImage(awindow,0,0);

// save the combined canvas to an image the user can download by right-clicking
var result=document.getElementById("composition");
result.src=canvas.toDataURL();
```

Since you're using images from different domains, I assume you've already worked through any CORS issues.  You might have to bounce the images off your server.

[image]

This example fiddle must be viewed with Chrome or Firefox (IE throws a CORS violation):

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/5JTtd/

Here is example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:15px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #sources{border:5px solid blue; padding:15px; width:380px;}
    p{ margin:15px 0;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var back=new Image();
    back.onload=function(){ draw(); }
    back.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    back.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/SPback.png";

    var person=new Image();
    person.onload=function(){ draw(); }
    person.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    person.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/person.png";

    var awindow=new Image();
    awindow.onload=function(){ draw(); }
    awindow.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    awindow.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/window.png";

    var count=0;
    function draw(){
        count++;
        if(count<3){ return; }

        var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width=awindow.width;
        canvas.height=awindow.height;

        ctx.drawImage(back,0,65);
        ctx.drawImage(person,0,0,person.width,person.height,200,125,71,200);
        ctx.drawImage(awindow,0,0);
        var result=document.getElementById("composition");
        result.src=canvas.toDataURL();
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Source images</p>
    <div id="sources">
        <img id="front" src="window.png" width=150 height=105>
        <img id="middle" src="person.png" width=48 height=133>
        <img id="back" src="spback.png" width=150 height=105><br>
    </div>
    <p>Combined result exported from canvas</p>
    <p>To Save: Right-click and Save picture as...</p>
    <img id="composition">
</body>
</html>
```