# How to save transparent Clipart images(.png) over background image as a single image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have overlapped some transparent .png images over .jpg background images using css, now I need to find a way to all images as single image(including all the overlapped images), so that I save it as a single image and have it for my use.

Detailed explanation : I'm working on a website where you could display some .png clip images over .jpg background image .To do that I have used some Div's each having images with single div for background image.and i have button for save image.. Now when the user clicks save button, I'm unable to save the overlapped images into a single image.

It would be of great help if someone could solve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save HTML DIV as an image with save as pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873682/save-html-div-as-an-image-with-save-as-pop-up)

Comment: no this is what you are saying....plz read my question..plz dont close my question..thanks

Comment: i don't  want to use canvas...

Answer (score 0):

For saveing all of resources like as css , js and images you use Google Chrome and after open developing tools (Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and go to Resources tab and then frames folder) you can find all of images there and you can save it.