# Javascript export div to image

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, image

I currently have a `div` tag that contains a bunch of other within it, and together they represent a line-graph. What I want to do is export this line-graph to an image(.png, .jpeg, etc) so that the user can download it. How can I do this?

It's a JSP web page, using JavaScript, jQuery and the back-end is handled by Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this can be done with a `div`.  But if you used the `canvas` element, this is possible:

http://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image

Answer (score 0):

From this answer: [capture div into image using html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595541/capture-div-into-image-using-html2canvas)

You might be able to use html2canvas to do the job. I've never used it though so I can't tell you for sure.