# Converting body to a canvas to save as image: "Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function"

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am trying to use html2canvas to convert my site's body (that has the id #body) to a canvas that can be saved as an image.

[Here is the webpage](https://lemory.kucdinteractive.com/)

**My script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function saveWebPage() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("body");
        var src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        document.write('<img src="'+src+'"/>');}
</script>
```

**My button HTML**

```
<button class="print" id="printButton" style="z-index:20" onClick="saveWebPage()">Download Collage</button>
```

Yet clicking the button produces the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function

I've found a few other forums on this topic but none with solutions that have worked for me.

I am expecting this to save my page's body as an image, but the function won't even fire.

Comment: Are you using the html2canvas library correctly? It seems like you're trying to use the toDataURL method on a DOM element, not on a canvas element created by html2canvas.

Comment: check this link similar question already there
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595541/capture-div-into-image-using-html2canvas>